# no puedo eliminar elementos por cada fila con for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Estoy creando un script en el que puedes añadir un evento y su fecha. Tal dia, el evento aparecerá en forma de notificación en el menu de Windows. He utilizado **SQLite** con **Python 3**.

Quiero que cada vez que se abre el **script**, se compruebe si hay algún evento con la fecha actual. 
Para ello he utilizado un bucle **for** que por cada fila de la **base de datos** comprueba si la fecha de hoy y la de cada evento coinciden. Si es así, borrarían dicho evento de la **base de datos**.

Este es el código:

```
def delete_database(row):
    """
    Delete task by id
    """

    delete = row
    c.execute("""DELETE FROM notes 
    WHERE message=?""",(delete,))
    conn.commit()     

def remind(end_time, verbose = True):

    """
    Check if the date limit is equal to the actual date
    """

    sql = "SELECT * FROM notes"
    recs = c.execute(sql)
    if verbose:
        for row in recs:
            if row[1] == end_time:
                # toaster = ToastNotifier()
                # toaster.show_toast("You have a event today!",row[0],icon_path=vars.dirpath + '\\custom.ico',duration=10,threaded=True)
                delete_database(row[0])
```

Creo que el c.execute(...) no deja terminar bien el bucle (loop).

Este es el completo en Pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/1njeHT7r

Comment: Te recomiendo proveer un [mre] y no solo un enlace. Los enlaces son solo de apoyo y no pueden reemplazar una de las partes más importantes de tu preguntas como el EMV ya que se puede romper haciendo inservible tu pregunta para los futuros visitantes.

Comment: Nos falta el resto del codigo, pero diria que usar triple comillas en """DELETE FROM notes WHERE message=?""" comentas esa parte del código y python la ignora. Para cadenas de texto usa simples o dobles comillas ( 'hola' o "hola" ). Quizas tampoco te ayuda el hecho de llamar 'delete_database' dentro del if solo si la bandera Verbose está activa. Eso no deberia de influir en la llamada puesto que Verbose normalmente se utiliza para mostar más información detallada del proceso y no si se ejecuta o no

Comment: @JoseRodriguez las triples comillas no tienen nada que ver. No son comentarios, son para docstrings o para crear strings con saltos de línea en el script... Creo que el error está más bien en que recs debería ser `c.fetch()` en lugar de execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connection.cursor.execute()` retorna un `None`

Para obtener resultados, debes usar `cursor.fetchall()` [o similares](https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/).
Lo que buscas tendría entonces esta forma:

```
c.execute(sql)
recs = c.fetchall()
    if verbose:
        [...]
```